# how Remove A Control From Ajax Mode Inside A Repeater?

Tags: ajax, controls, radajaxmanager

I am using radajaxmanager for getting ajax mode.

But many times I prefer to remove a control such as a link button inside a repeater from ajax mode (means repeater has been added to radajaxmanager).

How can I do this job with radajaxmanager?

That control goes in the right way and it is not appeared in the radajaxmanager configuration, and we only have repeater there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should use OnRequestStart event (client-side) of RadAjaxManager like below :

```
function OnRequestStart(s, e) {
    if (e.get_eventTarget() == 'bla') {
        e.set_enableAjax(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more comprehensive set of examples on how to specifically exclude a control can be found in the Telerik documentation here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-exclude.html